# Binding ip address of virtual interface to ftp client

Tags: linux, ftp, ip, debian

I have added eth0:1 with one more ip to the interface file of my debian box.
The thing is now i want my ftp client which is lftp to connect using the new ip address.
What was the directive to use a specific interface to communicate?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `lftp` set the `net:socket-bind-ipv4` option to the local IP address that you want the client to use:

```
    set net:socket-bind-ipv4 a.b.c.d
```

You can type that directly into the client but if you're going to do this regularly then it would make more sense to add it into your `$HOME/.lftprc` or `$HOME/.lftp/rc` file.

If you're using IPv6 then there's also a `net:socket-bind-ipv6` option.