# Force eth1 for FTP connection

Tags: ftp, debian, backup

I have this code for backups:

```
    #FTP folder create
ftp -n -v $ftp_server $ftp_port << EOT
binary
user $user $heslo
mkdir $datum
cd $datum
mkdir $cas
EOT
```

Server is connected to VPN with one adapter and to local network with secondary adpater eth1. I need to backup files to local network but when I set local IP as $fpt_server variable, there is "Not Connected" error.

This server is running Debian 8 64-bit in VmWare Workstation enviroment.

Comment: You maybe could try with `lftp` by choosing your client address with [`net:socket-bind-ipv4`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11235655/248390)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved it wih CURL upload:

```
curl --interface eth2 --ftp-create-dirs -T file.zip ftp://$user:$password@$ftp_server:$ftp_port/$date/$time/
```

But thanks for your answer ;)

Simon